# Bookmarklet dosent work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, bookmarklet

I could need some help with my bookmarklet.
I want to use the CKEDITOR on a extern page. The CKEDITOR.js lays on my local harddrive.

So, i need to include this file and replace the textfield.

I hade done it like this:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bfunction%20callback()%7B(function(%24)%7Bvar%20jQuery%3D%24%3Bfunction%20callback()%7BCKEDITOR.replace(%22product_group_text_de%22)%7Dvar%20s%3Ddocument.createElement(%22script%22)%3Bs.src%3D%22file%3A%2F%2F%2Fj%3A%2FCKEditor%2Fckeditor.js%22%3Bif(s.addEventListener)%7Bs.addEventListener(%22load%22%2Ccallback%2Cfalse)%7Delse%20if(s.readyState)%7Bs.onreadystatechange%3Dcallback%7Ddocument.body.appendChild(s)%3B%7D)(jQuery.noConflict(true))%7Dvar%20s%3Ddocument.createElement(%22script%22)%3Bs.src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.7.1%2Fjquery.min.js%22%3Bif(s.addEventListener)%7Bs.addEventListener(%22load%22%2Ccallback%2Cfalse)%7Delse%20if(s.readyState)%7Bs.onreadystatechange%3Dcallback%7Ddocument.body.appendChild(s)%3B%7D)()
```

I used a bookmarklet generator.
http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/

my code was just `CKEDITOR.replace("product_group_text_de");`
and i checked 'include Javascript' and 'include extern file' with `file:///j:/CKEditor/ckeditor.js`

But when i run it, it does nothing, Firebug and webdeveloper shows nothing. 
Maybe someone of You knows the reason?

Thanks alot !

Comment: It does load the jQueery, and does attempt to load the ckeditor.js file

Comment: Hm i figured out that the CKEDITOR.js cant be loaded.. but i cant understand why? How have i to make the URI for the local file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is... it can't work. If this were possible, everyone could read out your hard-drive and send the files to themselves.

The Solution I used was to set up an Apache server and get the data from localhost via that.

Comment: instead of installing Apache just for that, you can use CKEditor from its CDN: http://cdn.ckeditor.com/